# nvidia dual screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I can't use dual screen with my Nvidia card proprietary drivers (I've tried them all!), and if I'm using the open source driver it says I'm switched to an Intel graphics card. When the proprietary drivers are used, and I plug in the hdmi, the screen goes black and flickers from time to time. Is there any way to get the dual screen working with the Nvidia card?

Here's the [System Info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkFvq.png)

Here's the [Additional Drivers Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0p5n.png)

Graphics info from running **lspci | grep VGA** in the terminal:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)

**EDIT:** the following is in regards to a different lenovo laptop than the one i have, and an older version of ubuntu, but still..

> Some versions of this system come with two different graphics processors: an Intel UMA on-board adapter and an additional GPU from either nVidia or ATI. On this system, only the Intel graphics chip has been tested and certified. The use of the additional GPU is not supported for this release.

May just find a new distro that will support it if I cant figure it out soon

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with Nvida (gt710) :
Monitor connected on the display port on motherboard was okay but the second screen on GT710 hdmi port was completely unreadable.

My solution was to use a **HDMI-VGA adapter** to connect second monitor on the GT710 and it solved the problem. (I didn't even have to use the proprietary driver)